# Rails bootstrap not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-sass

I am following this [tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/simple-rails-authentication-with-clearance/)

But  the bootstrap for login and sign up page is not loading .Only I am getting upper header .I don't understand why is that....I have followed the tutorial properly .Is there some problem with bootstrap

[application.html.erb]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <%= link_to 'Clear Sky', root_path, class: 'navbar-brand' %>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar">
      <% if signed_in? %>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><%= link_to 'Add Page', new_page_path %></li>
        </ul>
      <% end %>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <% if signed_in? %>
          <li><span><%= current_user.email %></span></li>
          <li><%= link_to 'Sign out', sign_out_path, method: :delete %></li>
        <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to 'Sign in', sign_in_path %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>">
      <%= value %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= yield %>

  <div id="footer">
    <div class="container-fluid">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

[pages_Controller]

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :require_login, only: [:new]

    def index
    end

    def new
    end

end
```

[gem file]

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
gem 'bootstrap-sass','~> 3.3.5'
gem 'clearance', '~> 1.11'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
```

[application.scss]

```
@import 'bootstrap-sprockets';
@import 'bootstrap';

.navbar-nav > li > span {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  color: #9d9d9d;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: block;
}

#footer {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.other-links {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

[application.js]

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Where do you load the bootstrap CS/etc? You didn't include your application CSS or JS files.

Comment: What do you mean when you wrote "the login and signup page do not load" ?

Comment: bootstrap for login and signup is not loading

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `//= require bootstrap-sprockets` in your javascripts/aplication.js, see if it works.

```
    //= require jquery
    //= require jquery_ujs
    //= require jquery.turbolinks
    //= require bootstrap-sprockets
    //= require turbolinks
    //= require_tree .
```

I also recommend to use partial. so it is easy to read. for example:
you can create a file called `_navbar.html.erb` in the `layouts` folder and just paste all your code navbar in there.

```
    <%= render 'layouts/navBar' %>

    <!-- Flash Errors -->
    <%= render 'layouts/flashErrors' %>

    <%= yield %>

    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
```

much more readable... cheer mate!

Comment: couldn't find file 'jquery.turbolinks' with type 'application/javascript'

Comment: do you have this project on github?, want to test it myself.

Comment: Sorry I Tried but I don't know how to add project on github

Comment: Try restarting your server. see if you get the same error.